# Connect a wireless client to a remote WiFi AP which is not configurable

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, tunnel

let me introduce the scenario.

> **AP#1  <-----> (Linux #1) <-----> Intermediate Network <-----> (Linux #2) <-----> Wireless Client**

In summary, I need that an application running in the wireless client can communicate transparently with  Access Point #1 (**AP#1**).

As you can see above, I have a device named **AP#1**, which is generating a hotspot for a given application. This application can be used by associating to **AP#1**, and I want a wireless client to use it remotely. Since I cannot touch the configuration of **AP#1**, but I can configure **Linux #1** and **Linux #2**, I tried the following:

- **Linux #1** associates to **AP#1** using wpa supplicant, remaining in the same subnet.
- **Linux #2** creates an access point for the wireless client in another subnet.
- The wireless client speaks to a fixed IP in AP#1, and the traffic is routed and natted at **Linux #1**, so that the communication with **AP#1** is transparent.

So far so good, the wireless client can ping AP#1's address. However, the wireless client starts the communication by sending an UDP packet to 255.255.255.255, expecting that **AP#1** answers before the application actually starts working. Is there any way to route these requests back and forth or is 255.255.255.255 generally not routable?

I thought about changing this configuration by a gretap tunnel, but this topology is a little bit different from the examples I saw since I cannot configure **AP#1**.

So here are my questions:

- Do you think that this problem can be solved by establishing some
  kind of L2 tunnel?
- If so, what would be the best option?
- In that case, would it be possible to remove the NAT at Linux #1 and make the association between AP#1 and the wireless client totally transparent?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the noob questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you think that this problem can be solved by establishing some kind of L2 tunnel?

Yes, and bridges on both ends. But Linux might not make it easy to bridge a Wi-Fi client interface (see below).

> Is there any way to route these requests back and forth or is 255.255.255.255 generally not routable?

It isn't forbidden to forward broadcasts, e.g. Cisco IOS had that option, although routers don't do it by default in order to avoid loops.

I'm not sure Linux can do that natively, though it might be possible using an obscure iptables rule. It'll be easier to use a user space daemon `bcrelay` which can forward broadcasts in one direction.

> In that case, would it be possible to remove the NAT at Linux #1 and make the association between AP#1 and the wireless client totally transparent?

Not entirely. You can make it completely transparent at IP level, but a standard Wi-Fi client can only send frames with its own MAC address, so you won't be able to simply bridge the client Wi-Fi interface – there will need to be *layer-2 NAT* of some kind on the "Linux#1" device. (The "Linux#2" device is an AP so it *can* be completely transparent at layer 2.)

I don't know how to implement it on standard Linux, though I've seen ARPNAT in proprietary firmwares (Mikrotik RouterOS and Ubiquiti airOS devices) when they're set to station mode. I think many consumer "wireless bridges" also implement it.

(Linux does support associating in "4addr" mode which is fully bridgeable, but most likely your AP won't support it.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! :)